# Error: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, graphql, gatsby

## Overview

I use the gatsby environment.

Since graphql is used in gatsby, **useStaticQuery** is used.

It works fine in the development environment(`gatsby develop`), In the environment after building(`gatsby build && gatsby serve`), an error like the title has occurred.

**Error Text**

Error: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched.

This is likely a bug in Gatsby and if refreshing the page does not fix it, please open an issue in https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues

**Error code**

```js
const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allArticle(sort: { order: DESC, fields: updatedAt___seconds }) {
          edges {
            node {
              category
              id
              thumbnail
              title
              createdAt {
                seconds
              }
            }
          }
        }
        allRanking {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              category
              title
              thumbnail
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
```

※ Since it worked correctly in secret mode, I wonder if something is wrong with the cache.

### What I tried

**Delete gatsby**

1. `$ yarn remove gatsby`
2. `$ rm -rf node_modules`
3. `$ yarn install`
4. `$ gatsby build && gatsby serve`

**exec gatsby clean command**

1. `$ gatsby clean`

**change component name and file**

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24902#issuecomment-847926225

**delete .cache file**

### my environment

OS : MacOS

package.json

```js
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.6.7",
    "gatsby": "^3.6.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-clarity": "^1.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-dark-mode": "^1.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-adsense": "^1.1.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-gtag": "^3.7.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-twitter": "^3.12.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-calendar-heatmap": "^1.8.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-lazyload": "^3.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "5.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "remark-gfm": "^1.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  },
```

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to guess what's going on, as you pointed it seems related to cache issues, however, you've tried all the cache-related stuff. I'd suggest:

- Remove `gatsby-plugin-offline` and add [`gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker) since you won't be using service-workers anymore
- Check the importation path. It should be:

  ```
  import { useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby';
  ```
- Check the `SEO` component naming and importation (i.e: `Seo.js` or `SEO.js`). The same applies for `Layout`

Comment: Thank you for contacting us immediately.

I tried to verify one proposal.(Remove `gatsby-plugin-offline` and ...)

Then I was able to solve the problem well.

Thank you for your polite explanation.

It was helpful!!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me(Gatsby version: 5.11.0) considering you checked your Static Queries for errors and imported useStaticQuery from gatsby:

1. Clear the Gatsby cache:

gatsby clean

2. Update Gatsby and its dependencies:

npm update gatsby

3. Restart the development server:

gatsby develop